# Algorithm to add or subtract random numbers to array so that no number has a difference of more than 8

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

There is a series of 16 numbers which can be added randomly from the following set of numbers {-8,-4,0,4,8} but considering the fact that the new generated series shouldn't have any two number which have a difference of more than 8.

I am trying for an efficient algorithm which can generate the set of number which should be added without violating the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is slightly easier if you can work with contiguous ranges.  Here's a heavily commented implementation in Ruby:

```
# Note that generating from the set {-8, -4, 0, 4, 8} is equivalent to
# generating integers in the range -2..2 and scaling by 4.  Working with
# contiguous ranges is easier, just upscale before using or printing.

MAX_DELTA = 8 / 4   # specified maximum difference between any pair of values in scaled range
N = 16              # number of values to generate

data = []   # start with an empty array
data << rand(-2..2)   # generate first (anchor) value in rescaled range
(N - 1).times do      # generate remaining N-1 values by... 
  range_min, range_max = data.minmax    # finding min & max of current set
  # determine new range based on the current range + absolute constraints
  new_range_min = [range_max - MAX_DELTA, -2].max
  new_range_max = [range_min + MAX_DELTA,  2].min
  # generate and store new value
  data << rand(new_range_min..new_range_max)
end

# remap results to actual desired range
data.map! { |i| 4 * i }
# print results separated by commas.
puts data.join(', ')
```

This produces output such as:

```
4, -4, -4, 4, -4, 4, 0, 0, -4, -4, -4, 0, 0, 4, 4, -4
```

or

```
4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the area of this:

```
const numbers = [-8, -4, 0 , 4, 8];

function getRandomNumber() {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)]
}

function difference(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

function calculateNewArray() {
    const values = [];

    while (values.length < 16) {
        const random = getRandomNumber();

        // add any number the first iteration
        if (values.length === 0) values.push(random);

        if (difference(values[values.length -1], random) < 9) {
            values.push(random)
        }
    }

    return values;
}

calculateNewArray()
// [0, 0, 4, -4, 0, -4, 4, -4, 0, -4, -4, -4, -4, -8, -8, -4]
```

I didn't test it at all, appreciate any feedback.

Comment: my constraint is any element of the new generated array after adding the numbers should not have difference more than 8. But i didn't find this check in you algorithm.

Comment: In that case, checking the first random value will be used as a pivot for the rest of the available numbers that answer the criteria. Let's say first random is 4, the lowest next number can only be -4. After that, the only numbers that satisfy criteria is -4, 0, 4. (if first is 0, it's a special case) Hope Ive been useful, good luck.